# Click Events with Treeview in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am making a basic online editing outline for coursework. I want to include a tree-view functionality, that expands and collapses the parent node with one click. However, I can seem to get it to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <style>
      .caret {
      cursor: pointer;
      user-select: none;
      }

      .active {
      display: block;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="inputArea">
        <div id="bulletPoints" contenteditable="true"></div>
            <ul class="newUl">
                "header"
                 <li class="newLI">textContent</li>
                 <ul>
                     <li class="newLi">okay</li>
                     <ul>
                         <li class="newLi">yes</li>
                     </ul>
                 <li class="newLi">no</li>
                 </ul>
             </ul>
     </div>

<script>
   let toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("newLi");
   let i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".newUl").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("newLi-down");
  });
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem or question?

Comment: I want to include a tree-view functionality, that expands and collapses the parent node with one click. However, I can seem to get it to work.

Comment: @StephenAdams, Did you had a look at this ?? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_treeview